# Console shows UIView as null, yet it still acts like it is present

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I was debugging quite an issue where tapping the status bar would *not* scroll a `UITableView` to the top. I checked `scrollsToTop` and it was set to yes, so naturally I started looking to see if any UIViews were on top of it.

The culprit was a UIView I bring in that is the same size as the `UIViewController`'s view. I didn't think to check there because when I logged it out, it said it was nil.

**Like so:**

[image]

But then, when I call `removeFromSuperView`, scrolling to the top of the UITableView works perfectly!
**Here**:

[image]

I triple checked and this is the only UIView that is over the top of the scrollbar, so what gives? It says it is null either way. I am using ARC as well. I am guessing I am wanting `nil` here, not `null`. I was thinking if I set it to nil, it would put the retain count to 0 under ARC. Perhaps there is still a reference to the view somewhere?

Comment: When you set your reference to a variable to nil, why would you expect it to be anything other than nil?  You may have a strong reference to the thing, but that the view sticks around shows that so does somebody else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `settingsView` to nil does not remove it from its superview. It just nils out your reference to it. ARC or no ARC, the superview is retaining the `settingsView` so it's still covering your status bar unless you explicitly remove it. You could try changing the frame so it no longer covers the status bar.

I would recommend you try SparkInspector ( http://www.sparkinspector.com/ ). It is fantastic for solving these sorts of issues.

Comment: Thanks Dave, spark inspector does look great.